# Issue with image size (screen density)

Tags: android, imageview, screen-density

I'm starting a new Android project. I got all the necessary graphical materials in .psd files. The materials are designed for 1080 x 1920 resolution, since it is also an iOS app. I was just about to resize the images for various screen densities, when I ran into a weird issue.

Once I sliced a few images, I decided to run some tests in emulator. The test image I used is one of the menu images. Its size is 240 x 240 px and, as one would expect, takes about a quarter of screen's width in the .psd file. However, once I put said image in my app and ran it on 1080 x 1920 emulator, the image took up almost 2/3 of the screen's width. How is that possible?

EDIT: 
My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_tourist_info_selector"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Image I'm using: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2zgwwfp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put said image in my app and ran it

What does this exactly means? Could you share some code, where you put your image?

Without codes answer is not easy, but it looks like the ImageView's height and width are not set as wrap-content, but match-parent or fill-parent. Is this the case?

Comment: Edited original post. ImageView is set to wrap_content. Also added the image I'm using.

Comment: Thank you. Is this image in the right drawable directory? I mean, if the emulator has a hdpi density, is this image in the drawable-hdpi directory?

Comment: It's in the default drawable folder. Android Studio's graphical preview yields same results - imageview takes ~2/3 of screen's width for 1080x1920 xxhdpi device.

Comment: try to move it in the right directory (most of devices are hdpi), this could do the trick.

Comment: Ok, for the time being I copied the same image in all drawable folders and now I get expected results. Should I treat this image as xxhdpi resolution and downscale it for xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi according to Android docs?

Answer (score 1):

Android image resources are much different from iOS.

To understand how to resizes images for Android you have to understand "Density-independent pixel" or in short DP. You can read more about

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

A 240 x 240 px image will have different size on actual phone based on how many DPI that phone has (you can also see whole chart on the link above).

A set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi  
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi  
hdpi (high) ~240dpi  
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

These days mostly phones support these sizes mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdi (you will have all these folders for providing different sizes for each image.)

Lets say you put your image sized 240 x 240 px in mdpi folder. Now you need to put same image in hdpi, xhdi, xxhdi folders as well. Only then it will look same sized on all devices. Otherwise it will look smaller and smaller as you look on bigger screen phones.

You can calculate sizes using this formula `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

or just calculate using any of the online calculators like http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/